# How to share the same SysML connector in different Cameo Systems Modeler project blocks IBDs?

Tags: sysml

I assume it is possible to **share the same SysML connector** in a Cameo Systems Modeler project as other SysML tools such as IBM Rhapsody (versions 8.4, 9.0, 9.0.1) allow to do that.

- Fig.1. shows [image: connectorRap] `A-C` shared between [image: blockRap] `BL01` and [image: blockRap] `BL02` in IBM Rhapsody.

[image: connectorSharedRap]

- Fig.2. shows [image: connectorCsm] `CN01` in [image: blockCsm] `BL01` in Cameo Systems Modeler.

[image: connectorSharingCsm]

**Question**: Can [image: blockCsm] `BL02` "refer to" / "reuse" [image: connectorCsm] `CN01` to connect [image: flowPortCsm] `P1` of [image: partPropertyCsm] `PartB` to [image: flowPortCsm] `P1` of [image: partPropertyCsm] `PartA` ? If so, how can this be achieved in that SysML tool ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A connector is a *feature* of the owning Block. Connector `CN01` is owned by Block `BL01`. This Block has no relationship to `BL02`. What would it mean to refer to a feature of an unrelated Block? What would it mean to reuse a connector, that connects parts of a completely different Block?

As far as I remember, Rhapsody will show elements that you placed in the wrong diagram with dashed lines. So three of your diagrams simply show nonsense. Trying to make sense of nonsense really messes things up. Maybe Rhapsody should be a little more rigorous, when it comes to placement of elements.

You ask for reusing a connector between "PartA" and "PartB". And in fact you defined two Blocks that have parts with this name. However, that is a mere coincidence. They might have the same name, but they are completely separate things. So, what is it, that you want to reuse?

Do you want to express that A and B *must be* connected whenever they are used? I would model a sub assembly consisting of A and B and a connector in between. Then reuse the sub assembly.

You are using references to Blocks (shown with the dashed rectangles). This is possible, but questionable. If `PartB` is not part of `BL01`, it means it is outside of it. Ports are the means of connecting the inside to the outside. Therefore, add a Port to `BL01` and model a connector on the next higher level of the system decomposition.